# java CreateObject like it can be done with VBS

Tags: java, com

i'm new in java and i want to know how to communicate with com objects.
i have this code in VB that works fine , but how can i code it in java with no help of VBS ?

VBS code:

```
Set QNEEApplication = CreateObject("QNXMLInterface.Application")
result = CStr( QNEEApplication.ProcessXMLCommand(XmlString ) )
```

(it uses external dll and msxml)

i spend  a lote of time digging the net and also tried jacob with no success.

if somebody can help me it will be fantastic.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `"i spend a lote of time digging the net and also tried jacob with no success."` -- I'm guessing that your best chance at a solution is to use JACOB, j-interop or Com4J. Why not show your attempts with your question along with problems you may be having with these attempts. Without this your question remains a bit overly broad for this site.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

the problem is that i don't know the code to write with JACOB


Benny

Answer (score -1):

Hi
i managed to do it like with JACOB like that :
             ActiveXComponent QNEEApplication  = new ActiveXComponent("QNXMLInterface.Application");
             Variant variant = Dispatch.call(QNEEApplication,"ProcessXMLCommand",XmlString);
Thank you